# I'm struggling with nested comment feature for my blog app

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nested-lists

So I'm working on the backend of a blog where a user can interact with a post. I'm trying to implement a type of comment feature where a comment can have as much nested replies as possible.

here are my schemas:

Article

```
`const articleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    content: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    media: [
        {
            public_id: {
                type : String,
                required : true
            },
            asset_id: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            secure_url: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            original_filename: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            }
        }
    ],
    author: {
        type: String,
        // type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        // ref: "User",
        // required: true
    },
    comments: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }],
    status: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: "submitted",
        enum: ["submitted", "under review", "rejected", "edits required", "approved"]
},
    category: [categorySchema], // An array of category documents
},`
```

comment

```
`const commentSchema = new Schema({
    content: { type: String, required: true },
    author: { type: String, required: true }, //{ type: 
    Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" },
    post: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Article" },
    likes: Number,
    replies: [this],
}, { timestamps: true });`
```

so I have a comment controller that helps create a comment and it works fine. I created a reply controller and it worked fine for adding a reply to the already created comment but wouldn't work for other nested replies.

This is the function to create a comment:

```
`async createComment(req, res){
    try{
        const post = await Article.findById(req.params.postId);
        if(!post){
            throw new Error("Article Not Found!");
        }
        const comment = new Comment({
            content: req.body.content,
            author: "testUser", //req.user.id,
            post: req.params.postId
        });
        await comment.save();
        post.comments.push(comment);
        await post.save();
        return res.redirect(`/articles/${req.params.postId}/`)
    } catch(error){
        console.log(error);
        return res.send(error);
    }               
}`
```

This is the initial function to create reply:

```
`async createReply(req, res){
    try{
        const { postId, commentId } = req.params;
        const post = await Article.findById(postId);
        if(!post){
            throw new Error("Article not found!");
        } else {
            const foundComment = post.comments.find(comment => comment._id.toString() === commentId);
            if (foundComment){
                const reply = await new Comment({
                    content: req.body.content,
                    author: "testUser", //req.user.id,
                    post: req.params.postId,
                }).save();
                foundComment.replies.push(reply);
                await foundComment.save();
                return res.redirect(`/articles/${postId}/`);
            }
            throw new Error("Comment not found!");
        }
    } catch(error){
        console.log(error);
        return res.send(error);
    }
}`
```

This particular createReply function will only add a reply to a comment and not do so for other nested replies. So I thought to tinker around and came up with something like this:

```
`async createReply(req, res){
    try{
        const { postId, commentId } = req.params;
        const post = await Article.findById(postId);
        if(!post){
            throw new Error("Article not found!");
        } else {
            const parentComment = await findReplies(post.comments, commentId);
            if (parentComment){
                const reply = await new Comment({
                    content: req.body.content,
                    author: "testUser", //req.user.id,
                    post: req.params.postId,
                }).save();
                parentComment.replies.push(reply);
                await parentComment.save();
                return res.redirect(`/articles/${postId}/`);
            }
            throw new Error("Comment not found!");
        }
    } catch(error){
        console.log(error);
        return res.send(error);
    }
}`
```

This is the findReplies function:

```
`async function findReplies(comments, CommentId) {
    for (const comment of comments) {
        // Check if the current comment matches the desired parentCommentId
        if (comment._id.toString() === CommentId) {
            return comment; // Return the Mongoose model instance
        }

        // Recursively search for replies within this comment's replies
        if (comment.replies && comment.replies.length > 0) {
            const nestedReplies = await findReplies(comment.replies, CommentId);
            if (nestedReplies) {
                return nestedReplies; // Return the Mongoose model instance
            }
        }
    }
}`
```

from the error message, I can tell that the findReplies function does not return a model but just javascript object.

this is the result when i fetch an article:

```
`{
    "post": {
        "_id": "65083c03e13ccc61e42865fa",
        "title": "test article",
        "content": "Get some coconut, rice, pepper...",
        "media": [
            {
                "public_id": "Foodblog9ja/Media/1695043027956_1",
                "asset_id": "e97d2127ca2ebf503295a9589146f9e2",
                "secure_url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/foodblog9ja/image/upload/v1695043029/Foodblog9ja/Media/1695043027956_1.jpg",
                "original_filename": "wfh1",
                "_id": "65084dd700faf33389c5c79f"
            },
            {
                "public_id": "Foodblog9ja/Media/1695043027953_0",
                "asset_id": "1a9c22ee5da52f328f2248a4e26bd5ac",
                "secure_url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/foodblog9ja/image/upload/v1695043030/Foodblog9ja/Media/1695043027953_0.jpg",
                "original_filename": "wfh3",
                "_id": "65084dd700faf33389c5c7a0"
            }
        ],
        "author": "test",
        "comments": [
            {
                "_id": "65084f7000faf33389c5c7a6",
                "content": "This is a job well done... can I write for you please?",
                "author": "testUser",
                "post": "65083c03e13ccc61e42865fa",
                "replies": [
                    {
                        "content": "thank you so much... Mail me, let's discuss writing for us.",
                        "author": "testUser",
                        "post": "65083c03e13ccc61e42865fa",
                        "replies": [],
                        "_id": "650853d3d23e68f542076bc2",
                        "createdAt": "2023-09-18T13:42:43.577Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2023-09-18T13:42:43.577Z",
                        "__v": 0
                    }
                ],
                "createdAt": "2023-09-18T13:24:00.487Z",
                "updatedAt": "2023-09-18T13:42:43.590Z",
                "__v": 1
            }
        ],
        "status": "submitted",
        "category": [
            {
                "name": "food",
                "subcategories": [
                    "african food"
                ],
                "_id": "65083c03e13ccc61e42865fd"
            }
        ],
        "createdAt": "2023-09-18T12:01:07.810Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-09-18T13:24:00.565Z",
        "__v": 3
    }
}`
```

the other replies where the guy confirmed he sent a mail already does not reflect here even though the record for it has been created in the database.